# Username was trimmed after 24 characters without space in all posts but fully visible in Profile Page

Tags: bug, status-declined, profile-page, display-names, character-limit

I saw one user's name(Sudharsanam Muthukrishnan) is not fully visible as the last two characters ('an') were trimmed in [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33367247/2500920) and the first 24 characters without space is only visible but when I clicked the [user's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897100/sudharsanam-muthukrishnan), his full name is fully visible.

Is there any Character limit for user's name that should not exceed 24 characters? Is it a bug as it should show the full name around all the pages of the website?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a limited amount of space to display the user name. You may have noticed that that part is simply too short to display the full name (if you view the source, the full name is in the HTML). There is a limit to how many characters can be displayed in 150px.

Comment: Where it is mentioned in the site?

Comment: Um. Look at the site. Look at that area. It is not wide enough to show all characters. That's all there is to it.

Comment: :-D Ok ok cool.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough space in that area to display all the characters in that name.

The HTML source does have them.